# If I want to have 95% chance that less than 1% objects are faulty, how many samples do I need?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, sample-size

I need to make sure that my XML sitemap has less than $1\%$ rubbish (broken links).
The list of URL is in the hundred of thousands, and even if it could be feasible to test them all 1 by 1 I'd rather not, for many reasons:

```
1 - Saved bandwidth
2 - Faster traffic for real clients
3 - Less noise in visitor statistics (because my test would count as a visit)
5 - I could go on...
```

So I think taking a random subset would be sufficient, problem is I don't know probabilities.

Is there a simple function I can use?

If it helps, we can suppose to have an *a priori* information on the probability of a link to be broken across runs. Let’s say that across runs there is a $0.75\%$ for any given link to be broken.

Comment: How many URLs do you have? (Inference about a finite population is somewhat different from the usual case of inference about an infinite population.)

Comment: ?? a finite number obviously

Comment: That goes without saying, but which finite number?

Comment: in the hundred of thousands, every day is a bit different

Comment: What's happening to your site map that's changing it? Do you have a completely different site map each day, or are some URLs added and removed? If the latter, can you keep track of which have been added or removed, so that you only need to check new ones?

Comment: Not really, there is no correlation here. A link could be up one day and down the next due to an unforeseen bug. That's the reason I need to check them, as an additional safety net. Nominally they all work all the time.

Comment: Anyways, I understand what you are saying. One could devise a clever algorithm that further brings down the number of links to check. Yet still this is an engineering choice of mine. So I'll have to work with an equivalent assumption that the site map changes completely every day.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. One more thing: do you have a way of telling how big the site map is at any given time, or does counting the entries take so long that many more entries could be added or removed in the meantime?

Comment: I can explore and count the entries quickly, they will be considered fixed once the program start.

Comment: [See discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40196658#40196658)

Answer (score 4):

So it depends on the distribution of your prior belief about the breakage rate, but: about 3600.

```python
import scipy as sp

p = 0.0075
threshold = .01
confidence = .95

f = lambda n: sp.stats.beta(a=n*p, b=n*(1-p)).cdf(threshold) - confidence
print(sp.optimize.fsolve(f, 1000)[0])

>> 3627.45119614
```

The idea here is to model link breakages as a Bernoulli trial, and model your beliefs about the breakage rate as the beta distribution. The beta distribution [is conjugate to the Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions), and the way to update a beta distribution when you run a trial is pretty simple:

- if it's a failure, you add one to the first parameter, $\alpha$
- if it's a success, you add one to the second parameter, $\beta$

So if we start with a $\text{Beta}(0, 0)$ distribution and see failures about .75% of the time, how many trials will it take before 95% of the distribution's mass is below 0.01? About 3600.

Comment: One of those cases where Bayesian analysis makes more sense since the prior is not just a wild ass guess or worse an intent to manipulate. But perhaps you could perform a sweep over the $p$ parameter say from 0.5 to 0.9% and plot the corresponding required $n$

Answer (score 1):

For $n$ samples with $p=0.0075$ chance of failure, the variance for number of failures is $n p (1-p)$. So using central limit theorem, with $Z$ a standard normal,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\text{failures} < .01 n) \approx \mathbb{P}(Z < \frac{n (.01 - p)}{\sqrt{n p (1-p)}}) \approx \mathbb{P}(Z < \sqrt{n} .02898)
\end{align*}
Now we want the above to equal 95%, which corresponds to $Z = 1.645$. Solving for $\sqrt{n} .02898 = 1.645$, I get $n=3222$.